# How to associate a value with a keyword in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-7

I am using Elasticsearch 7.6 and indexing a list of keywords with the following mapping definition:

```
"keywords" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "analyzer": "std_folded",
  "store": true,
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
},
```

As you can see, the name of the field is `keywords` which will be given a list of words. Also, I defined `keywords.keyword` as the `keyword` type.

Is it possible to assign some value (a score) with each word? I am hoping to retrieve the value in my script query later.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

So if it was not with each word but to assign a specific value(score as in your case)for each field, you could have used something similar to [index-time boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) which is deprecated from 5.0.

If I understood, you can have multiple values for your `keywords` field like `foo`, `bar` and `baz` belongs to the same document. and you want to give all of the different scores like `foo:1`, `bar:2` and `baz:3`, **that's the score or boost on-field value, not on the field.**

### Solution: using [nested data-type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) you can solve this.

### Working example:

### Index def

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "keywords": {
        "type": "nested" --> note this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Index sample doc

```
{
  "keywords" : [
    {
      "keyword" : "foo",
      "score" :  1
    },
    {
      "keyword" : "bar",
      "score" :  2
    },
    {
        "keyword" : "baz",
        "score" : 3
    }
  ]
}
```

### Search query to fetch docs having `foo` and score `1`

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "keywords",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "keywords.keyword": "foo"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "keywords.score": 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": { --> notice this, it would bring inner doc `foo:1`

            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "nested",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.9808291,
        "_source": {
          "keywords": [
            {
              "keyword": "foo",
              "score": 1
            },
            {
              "keyword": "bar",
              "score": 2
            },
            {
              "keyword": "baz",
              "score": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "keywords": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.9808291,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "nested",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "keywords",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1.9808291, --> your expected result in inner hits
                  "_source": {
                    "keyword": "foo",
                    "score": 1
                  }
                }
              ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try and report back!

Comment: Thanks looking forward to hear back from you

Comment: @kee, any luck, please let me know if need further info :)